# Can I make the data displayed by Angular appear any quicker?

Tags: angularjs

I have a grid of data that contains many rows. When it is display it's a bit slow. Is there anything that I could do to speed this up. Something with the way Angular displays the data or with the way that it set up elements:

```
<div id="{{ row.wordId }}"
             ng-class="{current: row.current}"
             ng-class-even="'even'"
             ng-class-odd="'odd'"
             ng-click="wos.wordsRowClicked(row)"
             ng-dblclick="wos.wordsRowDoubleClicked(row)"
             ng-repeat="row in wos.wordsView = (wos.words | orderBy:wos.wordsOrderBy[wos.wordsOrderById].key:wos.wordsSortDirectionId == 1)">
            <div>
                <div>{{row.wordId}}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>{{ row.name }}</div>
            </div>
```

....

Comment: I suspect it is due to ng-repeat, to confirm it, reduce the length of wos.words array to less than 5 and try.

Comment: Yes it's very quick with a small number of rows. However I was wondering if there were other options to speed up the display of the data.